# Column renaming not persisting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am currently using SQL Server and I have to rename every column in a table.

For every column in the table I did something like this:

```
DB> sp_rename 'DB.TABLE.OldName', 'NewName'
```

And this worked every time.

Except for one single column where I have run this:

```
DB_configdwh_dev> sp_rename 'OCIDB.RAW_KPI_FORECASTS_DAILY.DEVRAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'RAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at'
Time: 0.510s
Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.
```

Though it seems to have worked, the old name remains in the table:

```
DB_configdwh_dev> describe "OCIDB"."RAW_KPI_FORECASTS_DAILY"
Time: 4.165s (4 seconds)
+-------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
| Name                    | Owner   | Type       | Created_datetime        |
|-------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------|
| RAW_KPI_FORECASTS_DAILY | dbo     | user table | 2020-05-24 23:31:58.410 |
+-------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+

+-----------------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
| Column_name                 | Type     | Computed   | Length   | Prec   | Scale   | Nullable   | TrimTrailingBlanks   | FixedLenNullInSource   | Collation                    |
|-----------------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------|
...
| RAWKPIFORDAI_predicted_at   | datetime | no         | 8        |        |         | no         | (n/a)                | (n/a)                  | NULL                         |
| DEVRAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at | datetime | no         | 8        |        |         | yes        | (n/a)                | (n/a)                  | NULL                         |
+-----------------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
```

And indeed I can confirm the column wasn't renamed:

```
DB_configdwh_dev> select top 1 rawkpifordai_promoted_at from ocidb.raw_kpi_forecasts_daily
Time: 0.356s
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'rawkpifordai_promoted_at'.

```
DB_configdwh_dev> select top 1 devrawkpifordai_promoted_at from ocidb.raw_kpi_forecasts_daily
Time: 0.867s
+-------------------------------+
| devrawkpifordai_promoted_at   |
|-------------------------------|
| 2020-05-18 00:00:00.000       |
+-------------------------------+
```

Since the renaming command does not result in an error, I am kind of lost here. I thought about copying the old column to another one with the correct name, and then deleting the former. But I believe there must be a better way to deal with it. I tried disconnecting from the DB and then doing the same process again, but it didn't help.

Thank you very much in advance or any piece of advice.

Comment: What does `sp_rename` return?

Comment: It returns this:

```DB_configdwh_dev> sp_rename
Time: 0.407s
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure sp_rename, Line 0
Procedure or function 'sp_rename' expects parameter '@objname', which was not supplied.```

Comment: What does it return when you correctly call it with parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.
The call does not seem to return nothing rare:
```DB_configdwh_dev> EXEC sp_RENAME 'OCIDB.RAW_KPI_FORECASTS_DAILY.DEVRAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'RAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'COLUMN'
Time: 0.610s
Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.
DB_configdwh_dev>
```

Comment: Each stored procedure has an [`int` return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-data-using-a-return-code). What is the return value of `sp_rename`?

Comment: I am not being able to retrieve it (sorry, I am not proficient in SQL Server):
```DB_configdwh_dev> DECLARE @ret_code int
Time: 0.356s
Commands completed successfully.
DB_configdwh_dev> EXECUTE @ret_code = sp_RENAME 'OCIDB.RAW_KPI_FORECASTS_DAILY.DEVRAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'RAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'COLUMN';
Time: 0.356s
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@ret_code".```

Comment: As one command. `declare @ret int; exec @ret = sp_rename 'OCIDB.RAW_KPI_FORECASTS_DAILY.DEVRAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'RAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'COLUMN'; select @ret;`

Comment: Oddly enough, it keeps failing: ```DB_configdwh_dev> declare @ret int; exec @ret = sp_rename 'OCIDB.RAW_KPI_FORECASTS_DAILY.DEVRAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'RAWKPIFORDAI_promoted_at', 'COLUMN'; select @ret;
Time: 1.069s (a second)
Commands completed successfully.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@ret".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@ret".```

Comment: Well, get a better tool to interact with the database, or figure how to execute this with the tool you are using.

Comment: use SQL Server Management Studio, which should aid you

Comment: Ty! I'll look at the problem from Management Studio.